# Why do we need weak or strong acids to displace the anions of other weak acids from salts?

Tags: acid-base, redox, identification, salt

I have already looked at [Why does a strong acid displace salt of weak acid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/133140/why-does-a-strong-acid-displace-salt-of-weak-acid) but I couldn't understand the answer and the analogy there. And I mean the above question in the following context :

$\ce{CO_3^{-2}}$ ion (from a salt) when treated with $\ce{H^+}$ from a dilute strong acid or a relatively stronger acid (i.e. relative to the acid from which the anion originated for example, for carbonate anion that would be $\ce{H_2CO_3})$ releases carbon dioxide gas. For example :
$$\ce{Na_2CO_3 + dil.H_2SO_4 \rightarrow Na_2SO_4 + CO_2 + H_2O}$$

Another one would be that when thiosulfate ion (from a salt) is treated with $\ce{H^+}$ ion from a dilute strong acid or a relatively stronger acid then two of the products will be $\ce{S}$ and $\ce{SO_2}$ or for example when sulphite ion (from a salt) is treated similarly one of the products will be sulfur dioxide gas.

Comment: What particularly do you not understand ?

Comment: Why do we need a strong acid to displace the anion of a weak acid ?Even my organic chemistry teacher told me that for an acid base reaction the conjugate acid formed must be weaker than the reactant acid, but why ?

Comment: @Poutnik my best guess i.e. why this reaction takes place is that sodium carbonate is a basic compound and hence an acid base sorta reaction takes place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be said at first: There is no real displacement. There is an equilibrium reaction of a weak acid/base and their salts, that form mutually a conjugate pair acid/base ( like acetic acid/acetate or ammonium/ammonia ).

All is then matter of chemical equilibrium. The stronger acid is, the more is it's dissociation equilibrium in favour of its anion and vice versa. So stronger acid releases hydronium ions and anions of weaker acids captures them, because their dissociation constants tell them so.

Sodium carbonate dissociates when dissolved:

$$\ce{Na2CO3(s) -> 2 Na+(aq) + CO3^2-(aq)}$$

Strong acids dissociate while forming hydronium ion:

$$\ce{H2SO4(l) + 2 H2O -> 2 H3O+(aq) + SO4^2-(aq)}$$

Meeting each other, sodium and sulphate ions are  just "spectator ions", while an acido-basic reaction happens:

$$\ce{2 H3O+(aq) + CO3^2-(aq) <=>> 2 H2O + H2CO3(aq)}$$

That happens because hydronium is much stronger acid than carbonic acid, while carbonate is much stronger base than water.

Stronger acid A  + stronger base B <=>> weaker base A + weaker acid B.

---

Carbonic acid is unstable and releases gaseous oxid:

$$\ce{H2CO3(aq) <=>> H2O + CO2(g)}$$

What remains in water are sodium and sulphate ions that eventually precipitates as sodium sulphate decahydrate:

$$\ce{2 Na+(aq) + SO4^2-(aq) + 10 H2O <=> Na2SO4.10 H2O(s)}$$

The similar things happen with thiosulphate.